# A technique of aggregating many input images to a single representation of the relevant features within

Tags: deep-learning, feature-extraction, representation-learning

I have a few thousand images and I would like to generate a representation of the foreground patterns within - a composition of all of its features, so to speak. In simple terms: take 10000 images of a dog and then draw the archetypical dog.

**Does this task have a name, and is there a method out there specifically for such purposes?**

The images have different sizes and neither scale nor rotation invariant, so simple averaging algorithms wouldn't work. I would guess that deep learning techniques could be capable - e.g., extracting the features from the first layers of a neural network - as hinted at [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/262060/123056): ..."The original network can't be used to classify new identities, on which it wasn't trained. But, the kth layer may provide a good representation of faces in general....".

I just don't necessarily need a model for prediction afterwards, just the aggregate representation will do.

Comment: It sounds similar to [eigenface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface). Here, PCA was used to extract principal components where each of them looks like an "average" of faces.

Answer (score 0):

This idea is more or less what driven the development of [Google Deep Dream](https://ai.googleblog.com/2015/06/inceptionism-going-deeper-into-neural.html).

They framed the problem in a much different way though, i.e. as a reversed task compared to classification. So given a trained network, we choose a final activation, and we modify a given input image till the chosen activation is maximized trough gradient ascent (n.b. not gradient descent).

[image]

You don't specify your definition of "archetypical" so maybe that's not exactly what you're looking for, but conceptually this is more sounded than combining feature maps. Reason being that a feature map is just an image modified with some filters, so the average of a feature maps is basically the same as the average of images themselves. Deep dream instead modify an image in such a way that this image will react to specific, already learned filters. So it's a generative approach. You can see it in the example below, where a sky image is modify to produce a "face" activation. All those faces are not training images nor part of the original sky image.

[image]

Note that if you're looking for a model that given thousands of images produce always the same output one, then the problem is simply ill posed. Even unsupervised energy based models like restricted boltzmann machines simply learn a mixture of features, not a single "archetypical" image (see pic below).

[image]

Comment: yeah I had thought about deep dream, but I guess I was thinking more of "statistically reproducing" the content of a set of images without being generative. "archetypical" might be too a humanizing - basically, I meant that I want a model to redraw the features or components that it learned to common features in the images I supplied before. basically you are right with it somewhat being of a "reversed classification" task, but I guess I will need to think more about the criteria that I want to apply here